# How can I install filezilla's shell extension?

Tags: filezilla, drag-and-drop, shell-extensions

I am trying to drag&drop a file from filezilla to some Windows program. I get this filezilla message:

[image]

How can I install filezilla's shell extension?

I use filezilla on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did install FileZilla using its installer, it should be enough to just restart your machine.

---

Though if you are using Windows 10 version 1803, the root problem is different and registration won't help:
[FileZilla can't drag and drop to Windows Explorer](https://superuser.com/q/1325683/213663)

Answer (score 5):

From the Filezilla wiki : [Re-registering the shell extension (Windows only)](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Using#Re-registering_the_shell_extension_.28Windows_only.29)

> Especially on Vista or Windows 7 it can happen that Drag&Drop fails
>   and you get an error message stating the shell extension doesn't work.
>   In this case you may need to re-register it. Here's how:
>
> 1. Open a command prompt as administrator. This is important!
>
>    Start Menu - All Programs - Accessories: Right Click 'Command Prompt',
>      select 'Run as administrator'
> 2. Navigate to the Filezilla program directory.
>
>    - Example (32bit): `cd "\Program Files\Filezilla FTP Client"`
>    - Example (64bit): `cd "\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client"`
> 3. Re-register the shell extension.
>
>    Type this command: `regsvr32 fzshellext.dll`
> 4. If you have 64bit OS, you need to perform an additional step.
>
>    Type this command: `regsvr32 fzshellext_64.dll`
>
> If you get the reply 'DllRegisterServer in ... succeeded.', you've
>   done it (though you probably still need to reboot your computer).

Comment: This does not solve the issue.